# I would like to answer this code to make a 3 by 1 grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

```
\documentclass[tikz,border95=3mm]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[case/.style={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm,draw},line/.style={blue!10!gray,line width=4,line cap=round,line join=round}]
\node[case] (a) at (0,0){} ;
\node[case] (b) at (2,0){} ;
\node[case] (c) at (0,2){} ;
\node[case] (d) at (2,2){} ;

\draw[line] (c.south west) -- (c.north west) -- (c.north east) -- (c.south west)-- ++(-1,-1);
\draw[line] (c.south west) -- (c.south east) -- (c.north east) -- (d.north east)-- (a.south west) -- ++(-1,-1);
\draw[line] (d.north east) -- (b.north east) -- (b.north west) -- (b.south west)-- (a.south west) -- (a.north  west);
\draw[line] (b.south west) -- (b.south east) -- (b.north east) -- (b.south west)-- ++(-1.25,-1.25);

\node[left=0.5 cm,above] at (a) {\huge 2};
\node[above=0.25 cm] at (c.north) {\huge 4};
\node[above=0.25 cm] at (d.north) {\huge 5};
\node[text=green,shift={(0.5,0.5)}] at (d.north east) { \huge $\times$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I am not used to using nodes and positioning in TikZ I have read latex draw tutorial but can't manage to make it a 3 by 1 grid, Any help?

Comment: What's a "3 by 1 grid"? How is it related with your code?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? A picture of the intended output would be helpful.

Comment: 3 squares across and one layer but keeping the diagonal line extending the bottom left corners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border95=3mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[case/.style={minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm,draw},line/.style={blue!10!gray,line width=4,line cap=round,line join=round}]
\node[case] (a) at (0,0){} ;
\node[case] (b) at (2,0){} ;
\node[case] (c) at (4,0){} ;
%\node[case] (d) at (2,2){} ;

\draw[line] (a.south west) -- (a.north west) -- (a.north east) -- (a.south west)-- ++(-1,-1);
\draw[line] (b.south west) -- (b.north west) -- (b.north east) -- (b.south west)-- ++(-1,-1);
\draw[line] (c.south west) -- (c.north west) -- (c.north east) -- (c.south west)-- ++(-1,-1);
\draw[line] (a.south west) -- (c.south east) -- (c.north east);

\node[above=0.25 cm] at (a.north) {\huge a};
\node[above=0.25 cm] at (b.north) {\huge b};
\node[above=0.25 cm] at (c.north) {\huge c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much I should be able to learn from this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    % size of the squares: 1x1
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        line/.style={
            blue!10!gray,
            line width=4
        }
    ]

        % border
        \draw[line] (0,1) rectangle (3,0);

        % vertical lines
        \foreach \x in {1,2} {
            \draw[line] (\x,0) -- (\x,1);
        }

        % oblique lines
        \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
            \draw[line] (\i,1) -- (\i-2,-1);
        }

        % place the nodes a, b and c
        \foreach \nodeText [count=\c] in {a,b,c} {
            \node[font=\huge, anchor=mid] at (\c-.5,1.3) {\nodeText};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}

    % size of the squares: 2x2
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        line/.style={
            blue!10!gray,
            line width=4
        }
    ]

        % border
        \draw[line] (0,2) rectangle (6,0);

        % vertical lines
        \foreach \x in {2,4} {
            \draw[line] (\x,0) -- (\x,2);
        }

        % oblique lines
        \foreach \i in {2,4,6} {
            \draw[line] (\i,2) -- (\i-3,-1);
        }

        % place the nodes a, b and c
        \foreach \nodeText [count=\c] in {a,b,c} {
            \node[font=\huge, anchor=mid] at (\c*2-1,2.3) {\nodeText};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3 by 1 grid (squares 1x1)]
[image: 3 by 1 grid (squares 2x2)]